# I'm writing a script that searches for an address with a balance sequentially

Tags: python, balances, explorer-api

So the program is simple. I start at a private key, for example

0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001

and end at something like

000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffff

I use etherscan and other apis to check for balances in batches of 20. I use the free api which allows 3 keys to be created and allows 5 calls per second. with batches of 20 that should be 100 calls per key or 300 calls total per second. Im getting more like 1 call every 5 seconds. Can anyone help with this?

```
import time
import json

from eth_account import Account
import etherscan.accounts as etherscan_accounts
import bscapi.accounts as bscapi_accounts
import polapi.accounts as polapi_accounts
import opapi.accounts as opapi_accounts
import arbapi.accounts as arbapi_accounts
import gnoapi.accounts as gnoapi_accounts
import celapi.accounts as celapi_accounts
import btapi.accounts as btapi_accounts

import multiprocessing

ethapi = ["D4QWKPKV8NE4RYTJWSAI4I77E6UNE77CNS", "D2HKMKKEWTBAJZIWUM2U4SZ5HKBGR3UN1H",
          "9PTC4HIR2JPPQZZVF9BBCK3C4295PTZP92"]
bscapi = ["6CVXK95H8SI27JPBKSA6KNGCEM2W7WZJ4H", "TWUA1AV9X8EXXJKJNXHD9HVIHY89ADSYYQ",
          "SUGASZ9BR8YHPHAN833R8AYAS23MZIGFZ8"]
polapi = ["PBWXI6Y5RBV6YQW1G4163ZV1DYXBHGRUJ5", "FT7YTMNZ4EVTY62A8HDPQY1DQ3QJKK4VIX",
          "U93TNNU3G7JGGM7MR71STV8Q3JX9GW3NXI"]
opapi = ["YH5RR86P3MFG3AV8SX5EVU4YX9PQCBNCP3", "ZPIDZHZMYSFGJ2H7UAZEZ6KKFQUA9M54SH",
         "7YGDD6NQ8C9KDX7P5QR6B1DWYNBDFK75TW"]
arbapi = ["F7H7HTH6A1YBKRBMIJZEZGACHG2KGUPVHT", "49PVUD7HVZAQ223MZRXQANZCDCCK23AE89",
          "UZKFZ5ZAKKBDHIF63B7PP7192NSE9IAX59"]
gnoapi = ["RKUA212TD496D5BHXUVTNEX5H8UWWKZ1IJ", "SWWJA8RZ9IHX2FR9ZAQGNDXQ33DW5NJHEG",
          "1KG5HYXVJP5PSIGQWC8TTMNS3EK3SV5MAA"]
btapi = ["E1D7MDJ1WWEA2U767P2QTMNHT8FAUT8XDV", "VMCATM1955861FN58HGG3AZWHJ7QECXBT5",
         "AZHXMGJRS3UZ2BMRGF1K911NF29UBF6H7V"]
celapi = ["H2QUH72BY33BJ8CHBKYI51PFSM2TJ34CJP", "JJ2GAFSKCW448UUE7N84ZJWMQPDY1ARRIJ",
          "UTT5GF5YT1X7P3MSBTNUXAX6ES37XI97N5"]


def check_bal_rev(start, end, eth_api, bsc_api, pol_api, op_api, arb_api, gno_api, bt_api, cel_api):
    winners = {"ETH": [], "BSC": [], "POL": [], "OPETH": [], "ARBETH": [], "xDAI": [], "BT": [], "CELO": []}
    prvs = []
    for i in range(int(start, 16), int(end, 16) + 1):
        prvs.append(str(format(i, '064x')))
        if len(prvs) == 20:
            print(prvs)
            pubs = [Account.from_key(p).address for p in prvs]
            eth_balances = etherscan_accounts.Account(address=pubs, api_key=eth_api).get_balance_multiple()
            bsc_balances = bscapi_accounts.Account(address=pubs, api_key=bsc_api).get_balance_multiple()
            pol_balances = polapi_accounts.Account(address=pubs, api_key=pol_api).get_balance_multiple()
            op_balances = opapi_accounts.Account(address=pubs, api_key=op_api).get_balance_multiple()
            arb_balances = arbapi_accounts.Account(address=pubs, api_key=arb_api).get_balance_multiple()
            gno_balances = gnoapi_accounts.Account(address=pubs, api_key=gno_api).get_balance_multiple()
            bt_balances = btapi_accounts.Account(address=pubs, api_key=bt_api).get_balance_multiple()
            cel_balances = celapi_accounts.Account(address=pubs, api_key=cel_api).get_balance_multiple()
            
            for j, balances in enumerate(zip(
                    eth_balances, bsc_balances, op_balances,
                    arb_balances, pol_balances, gno_balances,
                    bt_balances, cel_balances
                    )
                    ):
                
                for chain in balances:
                    if (int(chain['balance']) / 1000000000000000000) > 0.001:
                        chain['balance'] = (int(chain['balance']) / 1000000000000000000)
                        chain['prv_address'] = prvs[j]
                        print(chain)
                        winners[chain['tokenName']].append(chain)
                        with open("winners.txt", "a") as f:
                            f.write(json.dumps(chain) + '\n')
            time.sleep(0.25)
            prvs = []


def main():
    start = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"
    end = "fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141"
    num_processes = 9
    # Split the range into segments for each process
    segment_size = (int(end, 16) - int(start, 16) + 1) // num_processes
    processes = [multiprocessing.Process(
        target=check_bal_rev,
        args=(hex(int(start, 16) + 0 * segment_size), hex(int(start, 16) + (0 + 1) * segment_size - 1),
              ethapi[0], bscapi[0], polapi[0], opapi[0], arbapi[0], gnoapi[0], btapi[0], celapi[0])
        ), multiprocessing.Process(
        target=check_bal_rev,
        args=(hex(int(start, 16) + 1 * segment_size), hex(int(start, 16) + (1 + 1) * segment_size - 1),
              ethapi[1], bscapi[1], polapi[1], opapi[1], arbapi[1], gnoapi[1], btapi[1], celapi[1])
        ), multiprocessing.Process(
        target=check_bal_rev,
        args=(hex(int(start, 16) + 2 * segment_size), hex(int(start, 16) + (2 + 1) * segment_size - 1),
              ethapi[2], bscapi[2], polapi[2], opapi[2], arbapi[2], gnoapi[2], btapi[2], celapi[2])
        ), multiprocessing.Process(
        target=check_bal_rev,
        args=(hex(int(start, 16) + 3 * segment_size), hex(int(start, 16) + (3 + 1) * segment_size - 1),
              ethapi[0], bscapi[0], polapi[0], opapi[0], arbapi[0], gnoapi[0], btapi[0], celapi[0])
        ), multiprocessing.Process(
        target=check_bal_rev,
        args=(hex(int(start, 16) + 4 * segment_size), hex(int(start, 16) + (4 + 1) * segment_size - 1),
              ethapi[1], bscapi[1], polapi[1], opapi[1], arbapi[1], gnoapi[1], btapi[1], celapi[1])
        ), multiprocessing.Process(
        target=check_bal_rev,
        args=(hex(int(start, 16) + 5 * segment_size), hex(int(start, 16) + (5 + 1) * segment_size - 1),
              ethapi[2], bscapi[2], polapi[2], opapi[2], arbapi[2], gnoapi[2], btapi[2], celapi[2])
        ), multiprocessing.Process(
        target=check_bal_rev,
        args=(hex(int(start, 16) + 6 * segment_size), hex(int(start, 16) + (6 + 1) * segment_size - 1),
              ethapi[0], bscapi[0], polapi[0], opapi[0], arbapi[0], gnoapi[0], btapi[0], celapi[0])
        ), multiprocessing.Process(
        target=check_bal_rev,
        args=(hex(int(start, 16) + 7 * segment_size), hex(int(start, 16) + (7 + 1) * segment_size - 1),
              ethapi[1], bscapi[1], polapi[1], opapi[1], arbapi[1], gnoapi[1], btapi[1], celapi[1])
        ), multiprocessing.Process(
        target=check_bal_rev,
        args=(hex(int(start, 16) + 8 * segment_size), hex(int(start, 16) + (8 + 1) * segment_size - 1),
              ethapi[2], bscapi[2], polapi[2], opapi[2], arbapi[2], gnoapi[2], btapi[2], celapi[2])
        
        )
        ]
    for i in range(num_processes):
        processes[i].start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except:
        main()
```

Comment: I'd guess that throttling is done at the IP level. Try using different providers.